# Change data inside adapter for non persistent Model fields in Realm

Tags: android, android-adapter, realm

This is my Model Class where `isChecked` is non persistent.

```
public class MyModel extends RealmObject {

    private String name;

    private String destination;

    @Ignore
    private boolean isChecked;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

In my adapter I have to change the value of `isChecked` when user is selecting items in the list.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.Name.setText(myModels.get(position).getName());
    holder.Destination.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.Destination.setText(myModels.get(position).getDestination());
    updateCheckedState(holder, myModels.get(position), false);

    holder.label.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        myModels.get(position).setChecked(!myModels.get(position).isChecked());
        updateCheckedState(holder, myModels.get(position), true);
    });
}
```

But the value remains the same. It was working perfectly before when I was not using `Realm`.

Comment: How does the myModels look like? If you are using `new MyModels()`, the object created won't be managed by Realm. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primary-keys this doc might give you some idea about how Realm manage objects.

Answer (score -2):

Override the `onResume()`
Dont forget to `super.onResume();`